# Error Inflating Class Fragment in my app

Tags: android, json, eclipse

*my logcat is*

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException:        Unable to start activity        ComponentInfo{com.example.googlemapandroidv2/com.example.googlemapandroidv2.Promotions}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class fragment
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1830)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class fragment
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:250)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1712)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at com.example.googlemapandroidv2.Promotions.onCreate(Promotions.java:41)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1794)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    ... 11 more
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.googlemapandroidv2-1.apk]
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
02-12 18:08:51.707: E/AndroidRuntime(13169):    ... 21 more*
```

*while starting this activity. i am trying this app on HTC wildfireS 2.3 android version*

```
package com.example.googlemapandroidv2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.example.googlemapandroidv2.R;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class Promotions extends ListActivity {

private Context context;
private static String url = "http://expressdiner.ifeelhungry.co.uk/pushadmin/webservice/getPermotions.php";

private static final String ID = "idj";
private static final String TITLE = "titlej";
private static final String URL = "urlj";
private static final String OFFER = "offerj";
private static final String ENDDATE = "enddatej";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

ListView lv ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new ProgressTask(Promotions.this).execute();
}

private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    private ListActivity activity;

    // private List<Message> messages;
    public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        context = activity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    private Context context;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { ID, TITLE,
                        URL, OFFER, ENDDATE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.id, R.id.title, R.id.url,
                        R.id.offer, R.id.enddate });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        Log.e("INside of","Promotions");
        // select single ListView item
         lv = getListView();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // get JSON data from URL
        JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

            try {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                String idj = c.getString(ID);

                String titlej = c.getString(TITLE);
                String urlj = c.getString(URL);
                String offerj = c.getString(OFFER);
                String enddatej =c.getString(ENDDATE);
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // Add child node to HashMap key & value
                map.put(ID, idj);
                map.put(TITLE, titlej);
                map.put(URL, urlj);
                map.put(OFFER, offerj);
                map.put(ENDDATE, enddatej);
                jsonlist.add(map);
                Log.e(offerj, "Offer");
                Log.e(titlej, "title is");
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

*XML of activity is this in which i am trying to listview the data which is parsing through wevservice*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.googlemapandroidv2.Promotions" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your activity_main.xml file

Comment: try removing tools:context attribute from your LinearLayout

Comment: i tried but didn't worked!

Comment: try tools:context=".Promotions"

Comment: noway  it is not working

Comment: Its a ClassNotFoundException for some Google map class. If u have any libraries in you libs folder, related to that, add them to build path and clean build and run.

Comment: please read the documentation ... there was no Fragments on API < 11 ... also this code and layout seems to be not connected with an exception ...

Comment: i have no library in that @Kantesh

Comment: @Selvin then whats wrong with this activity!!

Comment: it is a list activity y are again adding a listview?
You can call getListView() right?

Comment: how will you please elaborate me ? @Kantesh

Comment: it this gonna solve my problem? @kantesh

Answer (score 1):

The layout xml file is incorrect (at line 30 in your xml file).

There is a xml tag `<android.view.fragment>` which is not a valid one. It should be just `<fragment>` instead.

**Update:**

If you inflate

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

somewhere, you have to ensure that that the `LayoutInflater` used is "created"  form a `FragmentActivity` (support library) instance.  Only `FragmentActivity` knows how to handle `<fragment>` tags before Android 3. I don't know where you use `SupportMapFragment`, but if you use it in `Promotions extends ListActivity` it will not work.

For example, are you using `SupportMapFragement` in `R.layout.list_item` which is used in your adapter? Then this is the problem, since Fragment only works in activities that extend from `FragmentActivity` (like `ActionBarActivity`). `ListViewActivity` does not extends from `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: Sorry which file it is ?

Comment: From the stacktrace I can't tell you the xml file name, but it's in the one that is used in `com.example.googlemapandroidv2.Promotions.onCreate()`

Comment: it is the same file which i posted here!

Comment: There must be a xml layout file that is used somewhere that contains `<android.view.fragment>`. Search for it in your IDE.

Comment: i checked every XML file in layout did not found any thing like this!

Comment: Hm, very strange. What about the layouts your `ListView` (Adapter) uses to display the items? Have you included the latest support library, since fragments were introduced in Android 3 but can be used before android 3 with the support library.

Comment: yep it is to display items and of course i included the latest support library.

Comment: *i think here is the problem*

     <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

Comment: That seems to be ok, but where are you using this one? it's not part of the layout xml file you have posted (R.layout.activity_main)? Have you defined your own fragments and tried to include it via another xml layout?

Comment: no this is used in another activity for map which works fine in android 4.2 but not in android 2.3 version.i also tries Support mapfragment.

Comment: supportmap fragment is not used in listview it is usend in map activity xml file

Answer (score -1):

I also faced this problem, I just clean the project and run it again. thats all.

Comment: this is more of a comment than answer

Comment: can you post your particular xml file